# Unable to match a URL in webpage using Search()

Tags: javascript, regex

```
walk(document.body);

function walk (node)
{
    var child, next;

    switch (node.nodeType)
    {
        case 1: //Element
        case 9: //Document
        case 11: //Document fragment
            child = node.firstChild;
            while(child) {
                next = child.nextSibling;
                walk(child);
                child = next;
            }
            break;
        case 3: // text node
            textAndGet(node);
            break;
    }
}

function textAndGet(textNode)
{
    var v = textNode.nodeValue;
    var apiBuilder = "https://unshorten.me/s/";
    var response
    var link = v.search(/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:0rz\.tw)|(?:1link\.in)|(?:1url\.com)|(?:2\.gp)|(?:2big\.at)|(?:2tu\.us)|(?:3\.ly)|(?:307\.to)|(?:4ms\.me)|(?:4sq\.com)|(?:4url\.cc)|(?:6url\.com)|(?:7\.ly)|(?:a\.gg)|(?:a\.nf)|(?:aa\.cx)|(?:abcurl\.net)|(?:ad\.vu)|(?:adf\.ly)|(?:adjix\.com)|(?:afx\.cc)|(?:all\.fuseurl.com)|(?:alturl\.com)|(?:amzn\.to)|(?:ar\.gy)|(?:arst\.ch)|(?:atu\.ca)|(?:azc\.cc)|(?:b23\.ru)|(?:b2l\.me)|(?:bacn\.me)|(?:bcool\.bz)|(?:binged\.it)|(?:bit\.ly)|(?:bizj\.us)|(?:bloat\.me)|(?:bravo\.ly)|(?:bsa\.ly)|(?:budurl\.com)|(?:canurl\.com)|(?:chilp\.it)|(?:chzb\.gr)|(?:cl\.lk)|(?:cl\.ly)|(?:clck\.ru)|(?:cli\.gs)|(?:cliccami\.info)|(?:clickthru\.ca)|(?:clop\.in)|(?:conta\.cc)|(?:cort\.as)|(?:cot\.ag)|(?:crks\.me)|(?:ctvr\.us)|(?:cutt\.us)|(?:dai\.ly)|(?:decenturl\.com)|(?:dfl8\.me)|(?:digbig\.com)|(?:digg\.com)|(?:disq\.us)|(?:dld\.bz)|(?:dlvr\.it)|(?:do\.my)|(?:doiop\.com)|(?:dopen\.us)|(?:easyuri\.com)|(?:easyurl\.net)|(?:eepurl\.com)|(?:eweri\.com)|(?:fa\.by)|(?:fav\.me)|(?:fb\.me)|(?:fbshare\.me)|(?:ff\.im)|(?:fff\.to)|(?:fire\.to)|(?:firsturl\.de)|(?:firsturl\.net)|(?:flic\.kr)|(?:flq\.us)|(?:fly2\.ws)|(?:fon\.gs)|(?:freak\.to)|(?:fuseurl\.com)|(?:fuzzy\.to)|(?:fwd4\.me)|(?:fwib\.net)|(?:g\.ro.lt)|(?:gizmo\.do)|(?:gl\.am)|(?:go\.9nl.com)|(?:go\.ign.com)|(?:go\.usa.gov)|(?:goo\.gl)|(?:goshrink\.com)|(?:gurl\.es)|(?:hex\.io)|(?:hiderefer\.com)|(?:hmm\.ph)|(?:href\.in)|(?:hsblinks\.com)|(?:htxt\.it)|(?:huff\.to)|(?:hulu\.com)|(?:hurl\.me)|(?:hurl\.ws)|(?:icanhaz\.com)|(?:idek\.net)|(?:ilix\.in)|(?:is\.gd)|(?:its\.my)|(?:ix\.lt)|(?:j\.mp)|(?:jijr\.com)|(?:kl\.am)|(?:klck\.me)|(?:korta\.nu)|(?:krunchd\.com)|(?:l9k\.net)|(?:lat\.ms)|(?:liip\.to)|(?:liltext\.com)|(?:linkbee\.com)|(?:linkbun\.ch)|(?:liurl\.cn)|(?:ln-s\.net)|(?:ln-s\.ru)|(?:lnk\.gd)|(?:lnk\.ms)|(?:lnkd\.in)|(?:lnkurl\.com)|(?:lru\.jp)|(?:lt\.tl)|(?:lurl\.no)|(?:macte\.ch)|(?:mash\.to)|(?:merky\.de)|(?:migre\.me)|(?:miniurl\.com)|(?:minurl\.fr)|(?:mke\.me)|(?:moby\.to)|(?:moourl\.com)|(?:mrte\.ch)|(?:myloc\.me)|(?:myurl\.in)|(?:n\.pr)|(?:nbc\.co)|(?:nblo\.gs)|(?:nn\.nf)|(?:not\.my)|(?:notlong\.com)|(?:nsfw\.in)|(?:nutshellurl\.com)|(?:nxy\.in)|(?:nyti\.ms)|(?:o-x\.fr)|(?:oc1\.us)|(?:om\.ly)|(?:omf\.gd)|(?:omoikane\.net)|(?:on\.cnn.com)|(?:on\.mktw.net)|(?:onforb\.es)|(?:orz\.se)|(?:ow\.ly)|(?:ping\.fm)|(?:pli\.gs)|(?:pnt\.me)|(?:politi\.co)|(?:post\.ly)|(?:pp\.gg)|(?:profile\.to)|(?:ptiturl\.com)|(?:pub\.vitrue.com)|(?:qlnk\.net)|(?:qte\.me)|(?:qu\.tc)|(?:qy\.fi)|(?:r\.im)|(?:rb6\.me)|(?:read\.bi)|(?:readthis\.ca)|(?:reallytinyurl\.com)|(?:redir\.ec)|(?:redirects\.ca)|(?:redirx\.com)|(?:retwt\.me)|(?:ri\.ms)|(?:rickroll\.it)|(?:riz\.gd)|(?:rt\.nu)|(?:ru\.ly)|(?:rubyurl\.com)|(?:rurl\.org)|(?:rww\.tw)|(?:s4c\.in)|(?:s7y\.us)|(?:safe\.mn)|(?:sameurl\.com)|(?:sdut\.us)|(?:shar\.es)|(?:shink\.de)|(?:shorl\.com)|(?:short\.ie)|(?:short\.to)|(?:shortlinks\.co.uk)|(?:shorturl\.com)|(?:shout\.to)|(?:show\.my)|(?:shrinkify\.com)|(?:shrinkr\.com)|(?:shrt\.fr)|(?:shrt\.st)|(?:shrten\.com)|(?:shrunkin\.com)|(?:simurl\.com)|(?:slate\.me)|(?:smallr\.com)|(?:smsh\.me)|(?:smurl\.name)|(?:sn\.im)|(?:snipr\.com)|(?:snipurl\.com)|(?:snurl\.com)|(?:sp2\.ro)|(?:spedr\.com)|(?:srnk\.net)|(?:srs\.li)|(?:starturl\.com)|(?:su\.pr)|(?:surl\.co.uk)|(?:surl\.hu)|(?:t\.cn)|(?:t\.co)|(?:t\.lh.com)|(?:ta\.gd)|(?:tbd\.ly)|(?:tcrn\.ch)|(?:tgr\.me)|(?:tgr\.ph)|(?:tighturl\.com)|(?:tiniuri\.com)|(?:tiny\.cc)|(?:tiny\.ly)|(?:tiny\.pl)|(?:tinylink\.in)|(?:tinyuri\.ca)|(?:tinyurl\.com)|(?:tl\.gd)|(?:tmi\.me)|(?:tnij\.org)|(?:tnw\.to)|(?:tny\.com)|(?:to\.ly)|(?:togoto\.us)|(?:totc\.us)|(?:toysr\.us)|(?:tpm\.ly)|(?:tr\.im)|(?:tra\.kz)|(?:trunc\.it)|(?:twhub\.com)|(?:twirl\.at)|(?:twitclicks\.com)|(?:twitterurl\.net)|(?:twitterurl\.org)|(?:twiturl\.de)|(?:twurl\.cc)|(?:twurl\.nl)|(?:u\.mavrev.com)|(?:u\.nu)|(?:u76\.org)|(?:ub0\.cc)|(?:ulu\.lu)|(?:updating\.me)|(?:ur1\.ca)|(?:url\.az)|(?:url\.co.uk)|(?:url\.ie)|(?:url360\.me)|(?:url4\.eu)|(?:urlborg\.com)|(?:urlbrief\.com)|(?:urlcover\.com)|(?:urlcut\.com)|(?:urlenco\.de)|(?:urli\.nl)|(?:urls\.im)|(?:urlshorteningservicefortwitter\.com)|(?:urlx\.ie)|(?:urlzen\.com)|(?:usat\.ly)|(?:use\.my)|(?:vb\.ly)|(?:vgn\.am)|(?:vl\.am)|(?:vm\.lc)|(?:w55\.de)|(?:wapo\.st)|(?:wapurl\.co.uk)|(?:wipi\.es)|(?:wp\.me)|(?:x\.vu)|(?:xr\.com)|(?:xrl\.in)|(?:xrl\.us)|(?:xurl\.es)|(?:xurl\.jp)|(?:y\.ahoo.it)|(?:yatuc\.com)|(?:ye\.pe)|(?:yep\.it)|(?:yfrog\.com)|(?:yhoo\.it)|(?:yiyd\.com)|(?:youtu\.be)|(?:yuarel\.com)|(?:z0p\.de)|(?:zi\.ma)|(?:zi\.mu)|(?:zipmyurl\.com)|(?:zud\.me)|(?:zurl\.ws)|(?:zz\.gd)|(?:zzang\.kr)|(?:›\.ws)|(?:✩\.ws)|(?:✿\.ws)|(?:❥\.ws)|(?:➔\.ws)|(?:➞\.ws)|(?:➡\.ws)|(?:➨\.ws)|(?:➯\.ws)|(?:➹\.ws)|(?:➽\.ws))\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/
    );
    if (!link.length) {
        return;
    }
    var URL = apiBuilder + link;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", URL, true);
    req.send();
    response = req.responseText;
    textNode.nodeValue = v + " (" + response + " )";
};
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't v.search return the matched value? I haven't messed with Javascript very often, but I'm attempting to make a chrome extension that will take any shortened URL on a page and display an unshortened version after it.

Now my regex does match the text if I test it in a regex tester, so I'm assuming my issue is the function that I'm using to set my variable "link".

Link is always empty regardless of the webpage. If I add a debug alert it always states it is empty as well, even if there is a link the regex would match.

Answer (score 0):

string.search returns the first match index of the given string.If you want to get the match result and group.You should use v.match(regex).